# Need to validate zapier cli input field with custom values

Tags: zapier-cli

I have a list of values and user input should be from my list of custom values. Please check my input field below:

{
  key:"timezone",
  label: "Timezone",
  type: "string",
  required: true,
}
I want to validate with "TZ database name" column. Please check below link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

timezone must be from this above list (TZ database name)

OR

I want custom validation for a input field. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Either of those options are possible!

We've got a table in the schema outlining which to use for lists [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-schema/blob/master/docs/build/schema.md#fieldchoicesschema).

For your use case, you'll have to copy that data into your zap and then use probably `FieldChoicesSchema` to maintain the order.